# Openwisp -> Failed to connect to controller during registration

Tags: router, openwisp

Well, I'm working with Openwisp and when I tried to register a device (router), I got this error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY25o.png)

This is the configuration on the router
[Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3jjr.png)

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION (60)
>
> The remote server's SSL certificate or SSH md5 fingerprint was deemed
>   not OK. This error code has been unified with CURLE_SSL_CACERT since
>   7.62.0. Its previous value was 51.

If you're in development/testing mode, you can disable SSL verification in openwisp-config by modifying /etc/config/openwisp and setting verify_ssl to 0.

In production you will have to make sure the SSL certificate of the server is valid.